# Can't mach build Fennec for Android

Tags: android, firefox, build, mozilla, fennec

i'm following this tutorial from firefox android source code https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android

but, the problem i can't ./mach build, ./mach package, ./mach install and i already create .mozconfig file in mozilla-central but it's can't found the file.
like this:

[image]

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2
thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably had an error during the initial "mach bootstrap" step. Your screenshot tells us, that mach can't find the android sdk tools. It's looking for them under ~/.mozbuild/android-sdk-linux/.

One thing you could do is to manually put your sdk under that directory and then retry "mach bootstrap" from the source dir to resolve the remaining dependencies.

Also see these steps for manual setup of the build tools: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android/Detailed_build_instructions